# xamarin.forms secrets.cs is not generated

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I tried it like it says here:

https://talkwithangel.com/xamarin-forms-app-settings-vs-user-preferences-vs-secrets/

Installed the NugetPackage (in all three projects)
Create a secrets.json file in the root.

FIll content:

```
{
  "KumKey1": "asdasdasdasd"
}
```

Compile the app locally.

Trying to access the file:

```
var searchApiKey = Secrets.KumKey1;
```

But Secrets isnt found by intellisense.

What am I missing here?

Comment: did you include the `Helpers` namespace?

Comment: It seems you follow the steps in the link. Check the file path first. You could also create a Secrets.cs file to test whether you get the correct key.

Comment: if I build my own secrets.cs it hasnt the same secret quality as the auto generated has or does it?

Answer (score 0):

In the root may not found your archive. Put the `.json` in a folder and include it on your class, e.g:

`using yourProject.yourFolder;`

PS: You may build/recompile your project, or close and open it again.

Comment: I did all of what you said, but it just does not show up :(